# Get SObject by Id

Tags: sobject, id

I have an `Id` and I want to know if it's possible to get the `SObject` with this unique ID ?

Something like :

```
SObject object = getSObjectById(myId);
```

I didn't find a method allowing that !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure you could do exactly that, but what you could do is use the Id instance class to achieve what you need, for example:

```
Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = myId.getSObjectType();
String sobjectName = sobjectType.getDescribe().getName();

SObject record = Database.query('Select Id, Name From ' + sobjectName + ' Where Id = :myId');
```

See ID class documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm actually doing. But if there is no other way to do it, I will keep this code. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't believe there is another way of doing it, certainly not one I have come across. You could also use the describe information to get all the field names too giving you a more 'complete' object.

Comment: This is great, just one thought. You can use string.valueOf() instead of getDescribe() there by improving performance. For example: String sobjectName = string.valueOf(myId.getSObjectType());