# Check if a record exists without knowing its type

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, salesforce-id

I am trying to have a custom object link to other objects without specifying a type. 
By that I mean I want to make something like an "OtherObject" lookup without specifying the type, so that I can link it to any object type. However, this does not seem to be available in Salesforce.

What I am doing as a replacement is I store the record ID of the other object. However, the problem is I need a way to check if that record still exists when I attempt to fetch data using that ID.

[Get SObject by Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45380/get-sobject-by-id)

seems to be only usable if you have a valid ID, is there any apex method that lets you do something similar with a String or something that may or may not be an existing ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to make an `Id` instance from your `String` value, which you can do with `Id.valueOf(stringValue)`. If you want to simply get a `Boolean` whether or not a corresponding record exists, you can do:

```
public Boolean doesRecordExist(String value)
{
    Id recordId;
    try { recordId = Id.valueOf(value); }
    catch (StringException e) { return false; }
    String soql = 'SELECT count() FROM ' +
        recordId.getSObjectType() +
        ' WHERE Id = :recordId';
    return Database.countQuery(soql) == 1;
}
```

---

If you'd like to avoid `try catch` block, use [`instanceof method`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_instanceof.htm) as `value instanceof Id`