# Get SObject by Name

Tags: apex

I see how to get an sObject, given an id...
([Get SObject by Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45380/get-sobject-by-id))

How could I do so given the sObject name??

```
string objectName = 'Account'; //(could be any object name)
//doesn't work ==> sObject myObj = objectName.getSObjectType();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getGlobalDescribe` which returns map of `Map<String,SObjectType>` SObjectName and related SObjectType.

```
SObjectType currentType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
```

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_schema.htm).

Answer (score 10):

`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` will work, but it is an *expensive* operation and thus should be used sparingly. I believe best practice here involves having an Apex class to proxy requests for `getGlobalDescribe()` so that you only ever call it *once* per transaction (and then store the results in a static variable).

If you don't want to bother with that, then another option would be to use the `Type` class that Salesforce provides. That'll be able to get you an `SObject`, which has `getSObjectType()`.

```
Type t = Type.forName('Account');
SObject sobj = (SObject)t.newInstance();
system.debug(sobj.getSObjectType() == Account.SObjectType);
```

Comment: Yeah this approach is actually the best practice.

Comment: Thank you all.  Awesome stuff!

Comment: Thank goodness the Type.forName parameter is not case sensitive! 

Comment: I'm now finding that the performance of Type.forName isn't that great either (though nowhere near as bad of the global describe).
I wonder if there's another alternative to this yet?

Comment: @RobBaillie Generally speaking, no there isn't and I don't believe Salesforce has any plan to change that situation. I suppose you could make a utility class with a static method and a private static variable/property so you could cache/memoize the Type instances so you're only ever calling `Type.forName()` once per class/SObject per transaction. I doubt that'd have much impact though. If you have a reasonably small subset of SObjects (known at compile time) you want to do this for, a simple static map or two with a bunch of `<object api name>.SObjectType` + `.newSObject()` may perform better.

Comment: Just ran a quick benchmark, and `Type.forName('Account').newIstance()` consumes about 0.085 of the CPU limit per call (and a similar amount of "clock" time). I.e. you'd need to call that 117 times to consume 10 CPU units. While `Account.SObjectType.newSObject()` is about 10x faster, there's probably going to be better places in a given codebase to go hunting for performance if limits are becoming an issue.

Comment: I found the source of my problem.  Type.forName requires that the underlying type be compiled.  However, it does not appear to store the compiled state (or at least wasn't in my scratch org).  I had some classes that were not compiled.  Running Type.forName compiled them (takes time) but did not store that compiled version, so next call did the same.  Result is that Type.forName performed badly.   Recompile all classes in the UI and the problem went away.

Comment: I'm still optimising for avoiding Type.forName being called when not absolutely necessary - and strongly suspect that if I'd followed the Type.forName with a type.newInstance, then the compilation state would have been stored.  But all in all a very odd scenario caused by the way in which our framework (previously) works.  Normally you wouldn't have a Type.forName referencing a class that you never actually instantiated.  Also, SObject classes will always be compiled anyway, so a reference to that would never be a problem.  Niche issue, in the best possible way.

Comment: Apologies for the red herring.  It wasn't related to SObjects anyway.